# run ubuntu on minimal resources (run terminal only)

Tags: command-line

I'm setting up an "old" pc to run servers for some games and I would like to free up as much processing speed and ram as possible.

My first idea is to shut down everything that isn't necessary and run everything from the tty1 terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>).

I don't need any GUI's to run game servers so just a terminal will be enough.

Anyone any idea if this will work and I should do this or if I should just go and look for another way.

I don't want to resize my harddrive to fit in a lighter distribution (if I really have to I will do this but I'm looking for ways to get as much resources as possible in ubuntu 13.04)

Comment: Why not install the server edition? There is no GUI to stat with, and you won't need to shut down anything. You might also want to know that 13.04 is reaching EOL in a few days.

Comment: Yeah I know. I should do a do-release-upgrade sometime soon. about the server version: I know but I just want to see how far I can get with my current setup. It's just a thing of lazyness vs functionality

Comment: So what exactly is the question? Just do it, and you'll see how far you get.

Comment: Well, the question was to ask if people had done this before. Saving me the trouble. Just like chemistry, if you want to make a new compound you always check to see if someone made a similar compound in the past to save you the trouble and time

Comment: If you're planning on running a server computer I recommend installing Debian, using NetInst. You can choose not to install a graphical environment and any packages that might be helpful towards the minimal feel you want in your server.

Answer (score 1):

You seem strangely averse to just installing Ubuntu Server. That would be the easiest solution to get you a headless-style system.

Other than that you just remove the desktop elements.

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-common lightdm
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

That will delete most graphical packages but there'll likely be rubbish laying around. It shouldn't cause any problems but it won't be as slim as a clean server install.

Or If you still *sometimes* want the desktop, you could "break" `lightdm` to stop it loading by running `sudoedit /etc/init/lightdm.conf` and comment out the `start on` stanza (it's split over multiple lines so comment them all out).

Then in the future you could start a graphical session by running `sudo start lightdm`.

But honestly, the reason people are suggesting Ubuntu Server is because it's the easiest route to success.